# What command can I use to detect when a minecraft record ends?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to know how can I detect if a "music disc" or "record" ends to activate redstone.

Comment: I don't think there is one. You could use a timer.

Comment: oh okay :/ I wanted to know if there was a command or something

Comment: Hmm... I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There is no way to detect when a record ends. However, as immibis said, you could use a timer.